# How to count same string in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, count

I have a little problem , I want to count same string in an array , 
for example
My  table like this:

```
    id |      data 
   ---------------------------
    1  |  @user1,@user2,@user3
    2  |  @user1,@user4
    3  |  @user1,@user5
    4  |  @user2,@user3
```

How can I count @user1,@user2,etc.. ?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to ask..

Comment: Your desired output is not clear, and SO is not a magical code generator anyway. Where is _your_ code? What are your ideas? What problem did you face while implementing them? You should also _format_ your posts before submitting them. All of this is covered in the help centre and by common sense.

Comment: I want to count how many @user1 are in my column data .

Comment: Can the string occur more than once in a row? Do you want to know how many times the string occurs in total, or how many rows it occurs in?

Comment: the string can be available once time by row , yes want to know how many times the string occurs in total

Comment: Are you talking about through SQL? Do you want that the appear as a result of your query or can it be done after retrieving the values? If it's the latter then I'm sure you can do it using .split()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use find_in_set to find data in comma separated field.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM some_table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('@user2', data)
```

This will give you a count of the rows that contain this string.

Note that this does suggest a database design that is not normalised and as this function can't use indexes it is likely to perform badly compared to a properly normalised database (ie, split the strings off onto a different table, with one row per string per id).

EDIT - if you want a count of all the strings:-

```
SELECT sub1.aString, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, ',', 1 + units.i + 10 * tens.i), ',', -1) AS aString
    FROM some_table,
    (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units,
    (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
) sub1
INNER JOIN some_table
ON FIND_IN_SET(sub1.aString, data)
GROUP BY sub1.aString
```

This uses a couple of sub queries to generate 100 rows for each row in you main table, each with a combination of the numbers 0 to 9 twice. From the combination it can calculate a number between 0 and 99 (can easily be expanded to add another sub query to go from 0 to 999, or more). It then uses SUBSTRING_INDEX with the generated number to split out the possible strings in data for each row. This will generate a LOT of duplicates, partly as the strings will likely be on many rows and partly because the last string on each row will be put out many times (ie, if there are 10 string, the last one will be put out 91 times due to the way SUBSTRING_INDEX is used). DISTINCT is used to remove these duplicates.

The result is then joined against your table using FIND_IN_SET, and COUNT / GROUP BY used to get all the counts of all the strings.

Comment: I want to do this for each @user2,@user3 , is it possible ??

Comment: Do you want this for every string in the data field? Or just a selection of them. Either way is messy

Comment: Yes I want this for every strings , I don't understand "select 0 as i union" , how is it work ? Is there another query to get the count of every @... ?

Comment: Not really. The `SELECT 0 AS i UNION` part selects the numbers 0 to 9 as fixed items. By selecting 0 to 9 twice it can use one as tens and the other as units to give 0 to 99. This is then used to split up your data field to get all the possible comma delimited string.

Comment: How can I split my array ?                                     example: SELECT COUNT( * ) AS NB FROM tablelog where FIND-IN_SET('@user1,@user2,',`targetArtist` )          I don't want to have @user1 and @user2 in the same query

Comment: It is not an array you have, it is a comma separated list. The code above (using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and `SELECT 0 AS i UNION....` ) splits it up. Not sure what you are trying to do with twitter log, but find_in_set is not going to do anything useful when you are searching for a string with trailing commas.

Comment: How can I get each string with @userX separetely to do my query ?

Comment: The query does that. Just tested it (couple of minor typos fixed) in SQL fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed928/3

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT COUNT(data) 
FROM your_table
WHERE data LIKE '%@user1%'
```